# How to set up http.Client to send https requests in Go with Cloudflare SSL

Tags: go, ssl, server, cloudflare

I have a server running in Go with which I would like to be able to make http requests over SSL. To use SSL/TLS with my server I'm making use of certificates provided by Cloudflare for my domain. I've added this code snippet below to give an example of how I'm attempting to make such an https request on the server.

```
func makeHttpsRequest(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
   certs, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("certificate.pem", "key.pem")
   rcert, _ := os.ReadFile("rootcert.pem")
   rpool := x509.NewCertPool()
   rpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(rcert)
   tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
      Certificates: []tls.Certificate{certs},
      RootCAs:      rpool,
   }
   tr := &http.Transport{
      TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
   }
   client := &http.Client{
      Transport: tr
   }
   request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com", nil)
   response, err := client.do(request)
   if err != nil {
      log.Println(err)
   }
   // code to handle the response removed from code snippet
}
```

However when I run this code, the following error appears when attempting to call this function.

```
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I am pretty sure that the reason this error arises is due to some misconfiguration of the files labelled by "certificate.pem", "key.pem" and "rootcert.pem" mentioned in the above code. Let me mention what these file names point to below.

The files "certificate.pem", "key.pem" are the certificate and private key of the *Origin Certificate Authority certificate* on my Cloudflare setup (https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca/) and "rootcert.pem" is the *Cloudflare Origin Root CA certificate* (https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin-configuration/origin-ca/#cloudflare-origin-ca-root-certificate).

If this configuration is wrong, what instead should each of these files be?

Comment: First of all, please check whether the target website requires mutual authentication (see [What Is mTLS?](https://www.f5.com/labs/learning-center/what-is-mtls)). If the  target website is `https://example.com`, I'm pretty sure it does not require mTLS. In this case, you don't need to provide a client certificate. Try `http.DefaultClient.Do(request)` to see whether it works.